# UWP NavigationView Foreground colour for the previously selected items does not update when selecting another item

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I've been setting up a NavigationView in the UWP project I'm currently working on. I changed the colours of the text using the correct keys. However, when invoking an item the item selected before the new selected item does not change colour. For this to happen, it has to be pointed over and exited. It also updates the colour when collapsing the menu.

I am sure the selected item is updated when another item is invoked. The old menuitems are unselected upon invoking a new item.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Provide us some code you are talking about..

Comment: It is not code related, it seems to just be a bug in UWP

Comment: You did't write any code? Please make it as easy as possible for someone who is willing to help you. Probably by providing sample project or at least pieces of code to reproduce the "bug"..

Comment: I have tested with official code sample, unfortunately, we can't reproduce your issue, please share the code or sample project for us and please tell more detail about the project target version and min version, OS version.

Comment: The navigationview code: https://pastebin.com/Efj7BHtD, I added the following to the rescources: https://pastebin.com/p7mAFuKA

Answer (score 0):

> I am sure the selected item is updated when another item is invoked. The old menuitems are unselected upon invoking a new item.

I have tested your code. I found you set the `NavigationViewItemForegroundPointerOver` same as `NavigationViewItemForegroundSelected`. If we select next item but the cursor over previous item that will make previous item foreground colour does not update. For this scenario, you could modify `NavigationViewItemForegroundPointerOver` to White to solve this problem.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundPointerOver" Color="White" />
```

Comment: The problem is the colours do not update until you point over. Once I select another item, the UI is supposed to update and make the previously selected item white again, since it isn't selected. Making the pointerover colour different does not solve the problem. This video might make it clearer: https://mitheace.nl/s/HdSRq83yQzginRFH

Comment: Ok, I got it, I test with blank sample, but I could not reproduce your issue, I think there are some sync method blocked ui-thread, could share the page's OnNavigatedTo and Loaded event for us?

Comment: Okay, I dont have an OnNavigatedTo, for it is a shellpage, but I have this for the Initialize and OnLoaded: https://pastebin.com/Enjg9qJs

Comment: Could you share `SetDate();` method? or move it to page loaded event handler?